# Email address of Logged-in User using JS Link - undefined

Tags: javascript

Someone can help me?
I use JS link for list and need return current user email.
Full script should change the fill line where an email user coincides with the current user:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
// Get SP content

var currenUserEmail;

var currentUser;
function init(){
this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}

// get user data

function onQuerySucceeded() {
document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
document.getElementById('userId').innerHTML = currentUser.get_id();
document.getElementById('userTitle').innerHTML = currentUser.get_title();
document.getElementById('userEmail').innerHTML = currentUser.get_email();
currenUserEmail = currentUser.get_email();

}

 function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
 alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
 }


 /* 
 Check that script works ok if need

<div>Current Logged User:
<span id="userLoginName"></span>
<span id="userId"></span>
<span id="userTitle"></span>
<span id="userEmail"></span>
</div>

*/ 
//Change filed email bacground color

function () {
var kpiFieldCtx = {};

// Define template variable  
kpiFieldCtx.Templates = {};
kpiFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    'email': { 'View' : HealthFieldViewTemplate }
};

// Register the template override with SP2013 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(
kpiFieldCtx
);

})();

 function HealthFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {

 var _healthValue = ctx.CurrentItem.email;

 if (_healthValue == 'Green') //field value
  {
   return "<li style='background-color:  #FF0000'>"+currenUserEmail+"</li></span>";
  }

  if (_healthValue == 'Yellow')
  {
    return "<img src='/SiteAssets/yellow.png'/>";
  } 

  if (_healthValue == 'Red')
  {
     return "<img src='/SiteAssets/red.png'/>";
  }            
  }
```

But it return “undefined”
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',function(){  
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_web();
  var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
  context.load(currentUser);
  context.executeQueryAsync(
  function(){
      alert(currentUser.get_email()); 
  }, 
  function(sender, args){
      console.log('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var currentuseremail;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
function init(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    this.currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
        currentuseremail = this.currentUser.get_email();
}
```

Comment: Still not working, Thank you very much for your help !!!!!!